# Why does docker-compose issue the "wrong" exit code when errors occur?

Tags: linux, docker, bash, cron, command-line-interface

I created a bash script to automate a borg backup of a running docker container. Before the backup is started, the container should be paused. The script should be executed only after the container has been paused successfully.

But now I get an error that the container could not be paused. However, docker-compose issues the exit code 0 and the script continues to run.

Here is a snippet from my script:

```bash
echo "Pausing container ..."
docker-compose \
  --file [...] \
  --project-directory [...] \
  pause
docker_exit=$?

## don't start backup if container isn't paused
if [ ${docker_exit} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "... container paused successfully"
elif [ ${docker_exit} -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "... container not paused with warnings"
    echo "Logfile for backup script: ${log}"
    exit ${docker_exit}
else
    echo "... container not paused with errors"
    echo "Logfile for backup script: ${log}"
    exit ${docker_exit}
fi
```

When the script is executed via cron I get the following output in the log file:

```
Pausing container ...
Pausing [...] ...
^[[1A^[[2K^MPausing [...] ... ^[[31merror^[[0m^M^[[1B
ERROR: for [...]  Cannot pause container [...]: OCI runtime pause failed: unable to freeze: unknown
... container paused successfully
```

I already tried to find a hint in the official docker docs but only ended up at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#options where I found the docker-compose option "--exit-code-from" which is not the right solution.

So maybe someone sees my mistake and could help me? Thanks a lot!

PS If something is not understandable or some details are missing I will add it if you give me a hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a strange one.
I think `docker-compose` should be passing the exit code from the underlying docker cli, so it's either a bug or the problem lies deeper. If I'm not mistaken, the "stack" is `docker-compose` -> `docker` -> `cgroup freezer`

I suggest doing a test run of the script using just `docker` cli (without compose) on individual containers to harvest the exit codes. If the exit codes are correct (=not always 0), then it's likely a bug in `docker-compose`.

Another option is to hunt down the reason why the pause fails :) Does the script behave this way only when run from crontab? Is the docker-compose for something publicly available so I can reproduce it?

Comment: **"I suggest doing a test run of the script using just docker cli (without compose)"**
Yes, that's a good idea and I will try that.

**"Does the script behave this way only when run from crontab?"**
That is hard to say because on some days the script runs through without errors (because the container paused successfully)

**"Is the docker-compose for something publicly available so I can reproduce it?"**
No, sorry it is not available. Or do you just mean the docker-compose file?

Comment: And I know there is a second problem I have to solve: why the container isn't pausing correctly but in this question I would stick to the first problem: "why will the script be executed even if docker-compose stops with errors"

Comment: Let me know how using docker cli works out. You could also try if compose v2 behaves differently. If it ends up being a compose bug, it should be reported to v2 anyway, as v1 is no longer maintained. Debian packages compose v2 as `docker-compose-plugin`

Or if you want to do it the quick 'n' dirty way, save the output of docker-compose pause to a variable and check if the output contains a string (like "failed"). Not ideal, but may get the job done :)

Comment: Right now I'm pausing the container with the cli `docker pause CONTAINER_ID` and it seems to work. The upgrade to compose v2 is scheduled and I'll try it with compose v2 and I'll give feedback in this thread.

Thanks for your help!